# Textures sometimes become suddenly black or white

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

Sometimes the textures of the character that I’m creating suddenly become black or white,even if :

1. the method to display/shade object in the 3d view = material
2. properties / object / display / maximum draw type = textured
3. properties / object / display / object color = white
4. render = cycles
5. if method to display/shade object in the 3d view = texture => the
   textures are grey
6. if method to display/shade object in the 3d view = rendered => they
   work correctly

[Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ixyIzmk1UiDe_cO997KLIonQ9crtrizb) you can find the blender file of the character that I’m working with.

This is how it appears :

[image: abc]

Comment: I open the file and couldn't replicate your problem, maybe you are viewing the output of a specific node instead of the entire tree?

Comment: I have opened another blender session with the same file and it works...but it does not work on the first blender session. I don't know why. what do you mean with "maybe you are viewing the output of a specific node instead of the entire tree" ? what should I do ?

Comment: Maybe double check the node editor(bottom window) to see if the output node is attached to the one you wanted. But since I cant replicate the problem, I dont know what is the issue, sry.

Comment: Are the lamps on another layer? You could have suddenly deselected the layer for the lighting, I know, because I have.

Comment: It’s happened again. This time I can give more details. The textures became translucent dark gray after that I have separated the eyelash from the rest of the body. And I’m not selecting any material on the node editor…when I click on “human_mblab_skin_diffuse” or on “human_mblab_skin_disp” node on the node editor nothing happens. The textures are again translucent dark gray.

Comment: I created a post also here : https://blenderartists.org/t/textures-sometimes-become-suddenly-black-or-white/1119799/5